# Rank entire dataframe excluding string columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to look for percentile of each floating column while keeping str columns unchanged.
I used `df.rank(pct=True)` however that also ranks str columns.

[image]

I would like to avoid listing all floating columns in the code as there are many of them, but have just a few string columns.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.rank(pct=True, numeric_only=True)
```

You can also add the pct_rank values to the original dataframe columns

```
pd.concat([df[[''Category', 'Name'']], 
           df.rank(pct=True, numeric_only=True)], 
           axis='columns')
```

Or add the pct columns with a prefix to the original dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df, 
           df.rank(pct=True, numeric_only=True).add_prefix('pct_')], 
          axis='columns')
```

Comment: Thanks, however it hides 1st 2 columns, any way I could keep them as well?

Comment: hmm, it shows an error "Wrong number of items passed 166, placement implies 1"

Comment: @mjspier - better is more dynamic solution for extract numeric columns, here is possible some non numeric columns should be omit, because selecting manually...

Comment: Yes, you had several numerical columns of course and then the assignment to one column does not work. The updated solution should work though.

Answer (score 0):

Select only numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and apply `rank` only for these columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

num_cols = df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns
df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].rank(pct=True)
print (df)
   A         B         C         D         E  F
0  a  0.333333  0.666667  0.416667  0.666667  a
1  b  0.833333  0.833333  0.666667  0.333333  a
2  c  0.333333  1.000000  0.833333  0.833333  a
3  d  0.833333  0.500000  1.000000  1.000000  b
4  e  0.833333  0.166667  0.416667  0.166667  b
5  f  0.333333  0.333333  0.166667  0.500000  b
```

Comment: This method gave me an error " include and exclude must both be non-string sequences"

Comment: @user54083 - so need `num_cols = df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns` ?